# How to upload a credential.json file to Hasura cluster without adding it to a git remote repository

Tags: kubernetes, hasura

I am supposed to use a credvalue.json in some API being used by the program, but I don't want to upload this credentials to GitHub repository and still use it in microservice

I tried adding it to .gitignore and copying it to src folder in docker but it results in file not found, but if I remove it from . gitignore it works well

I can't use hasura secrets, it's the credvalue.json file required by the library

Also just for a use case, the API requires me to specify the path of this JSON file as an environment variables, so what should be the path of file uploaded JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `hasura secrets` with files as well with the `-f` flag.

Here are the link to the docs: https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/project/secrets/mounting-secret-as-file.html

You can basically create a secret from a file and then mount that secret as a file your microservice container.